# CKEditor4, Easy Image, Token and PHP

Tags: php, ckeditor4

Here https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_easyimage_integration.html (useless tutorial) i can read the next lines:

```
cloudServices_tokenUrl: 'https://example.com/cs-token-endpoint',
cloudServices_uploadUrl: 'https://your-organization-id.cke-cs.com/easyimage/upload/'
```

Can somebody know how are to be the php files

```
cs-token-endpoint.php
easyimage-upload.php
```

What cause in browser console error `Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since its 'w' descriptor is invalid.`. Thank you.